# showing some kinda runtime error for the progran that prints YES if thers a common substring between two strings

Tags: python-3.x

- 

Given two strings, determine if they share a common substring. A substring may be as small as one character.

For example, the words "a", "and", "art" share the common substring. The words "be" and "cat" do not share a substring.
Complete the function twoStrings in the editor below. It should return a string, either YES or NO based on whether the strings share a common substring.

twoStrings has the following parameter(s):

s1, s2: two strings to analyze .
Input Format

The first line contains a single integer , the number of test cases.

The following  pairs of lines are as follows:

The first line contains string .
The second line contains string .
*

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the twoStrings function below.
def twoStrings(s1, s2):
    `this is the code i have written its been showing some kinda runtime error`
    str1 = list(s1)
    str2 = list(s2)
    flag = 0
    for i in str1:
        for j in str2:
            if str(i) == str(j):
                flag += 1

    if flag > 0:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    q = int(input())

    for q_itr in range(q):
        s1 = input()

        s2 = input()

        result = twoStrings(s1, s2)

        fptr.write(result + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking for help with code that causes an error, please make sure you include the error (as text) rather than simply saying there's 'some kinda runtime error'. The error might not make sense to you, but will almost always help others pinpoint your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's sufficient to determine whether or not the two strings share a single character.  One way to do this is to create a set of characters in the first string, then check every character in the second string against that set.

```
def share_char(s1, s2):
    s1_chars = set(s1)
    return any(s2_char in s1_chars for s2_char in s2)
```